Would a "fist bump" be considered the best option overall for respectful touching between the sexes?
During Covid there developed a new habit for greeting people who were concerned about spreading germs. Instead of shaking someone's hand, you were encouraged to fist bump.
You would literally make a fist and you'd just tap knuckles as an alternative to handshaking.
That got me thinking about negiah rules in general and whether this form of touching may be the most appropriate form of touch for mixed gender situations.
I know that when it comes to touching between the sexes, opinions vary depending on rabbinical source. Some Jews refrain from handshakes at all while other authorities differentiate types of touch (as in as long as the touch isn't affection based, it isn't problematic)
Would a fist bump between sexes actually be the best option overall?
My logic is this.
Touching of hands can actually be an intimate act. The surface of the palm contains many nerve endings and these nerve endings can be stimulated through touch which may or may not be appropriate depending on the situation. Sensual hand touching is very much a practiced act.
Fist bumping circumvents the issue entirely. Our knuckles are a bony outgrowth on our hands. There are nowhere near as many nerve endings as there are on the palms of our hands. A fist bump allows two Jews of the opposite sexes to show greetings and affection without touching parts of the body which may become stimulated by skin on skin contact.
I'd argue fist bumping may actually be the best form of greeting for observant Jews (outside of no touching at all)
I'm curious as to whether this topic has been discussed and if the logic I am using follows based on contemporary interpretations of Jewish practice?

What about elbow bumping?

In most cases of human relations between the sexes occurs, touch is not necessary. In the few cases where it is an issue, it usually is because of handshakes. E.g. a job interview, or meeting a client, or whatever. So, offering a fist bump in those situations instead of a handshake usually would be just as weird as politely refusing, with explanation. So, I'm not sure what we'd gain by this line of thought? Unless you are hoping to start a movement of encouraging men and women who already shake hands to switch to fist bumps? :) Anyway, I don't think I've seen nerve endings come up on topic b4

fist bumps are generally more of a sign of friendship than a handshake. Biden had the same thought process as you and fistbumped MBS instead of a handshake but received backlash since most people thought the opposite.
